# Typescript CORS enabled but still getting CORS error

Tags: typescript, cors

I have added a cors header in my Angular 7.0.5 project but i am still getting the following error when submitting a form and sending the form data to a 'back-end' (google script):

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://script.google.com/blabla' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am not receiving this error when i try this in Chrome with disabled security.

Might be a syntax error but i have been searching for a long time and tried a lot of things but i can't get it working.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ContactFormDto} from '../services/dto/contactform.dto';

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'undefined')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact',
    templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact.component.sass']
})

export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

contactForm: FormGroup;
submitted = false;

MAIL_SCRIPT_URL = 
'https://script.google.com/scriptlocation';

private contactFormDto: ContactFormDto;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       name: ['', Validators.required],
       email: ['', Validators.required],
       message: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}

onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.contactForm.valid) {
  this.contactFormDto = new ContactFormDto(
    this.contactForm.controls.name.value,
    this.contactForm.controls.email.value,
    this.contactForm.controls.message.value
  );

  this.http.post(
    this.MAIL_SCRIPT_URL,
    this.contactFormDto,
    {headers}
  ).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('Mail has been sent' + data);
  }, error => {
    console.log('Mail has not been sent ' + error);
  });

  console.log('name: ' + this.contactForm.controls.name.value + ' email: ' + 
  this.contactForm.controls.email.value + ' message: ' + 
  this.contactForm.controls.message.value);
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
}
```

The 'backend' is a google script (runs when i post the form results to the url)

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "myaddress@gmail.com"; // where to send form data

function doPost(e) {

try {
  Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class 
  Logger
  MailApp.sendEmail(TO_ADDRESS, "Contact Form Submitted",
                  JSON.stringify(e.parameters));
  // return json success results
  return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(
        JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                        "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} catch(error) { // if error return this
  Logger.log(error);
  return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

Comment: use this google chrome extension `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en`

Comment: Have you authorized preflight requests ? These are `OPTIONS` requests made by the browser.

Comment: Also, as this has nothing to do with Angular, I highly suggest you update your code with your backend code, and the tags with the corresponding language, before your question gets edited (like, by me in five minutes)

Comment: What is your backed framework because there is nothing to do with angular

Answer (score -5, accepted):

If you want Easiest way you can use plugins.

```
Allow-Control-Allow-Origin
```

URL LINK: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: this answer maybe help to other's they can easily see the answer.

Comment: That's not an answer, and it won't help anyone with an issue. That's basically promoting a plugin, not answering a question.

Comment: I think this would only work on my pc, and it would not work when the application get's deployed. Or am i wrong here?